# how to change jvm parameters on the Microsoft Azure website

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, jvm, jvm-arguments

I created a java-based website on Azure, and selected tomcat as container when used "CUSTOM CREATE", then there is an empty website ready and I can upload WAR files using ftp but not able to touch tomcat files. I need change the heap size of JVM, how to do that?

Comment: @markspace , yes, I understand. actually we use Azure for our .net websites mostly, and java-base site is only solr server, we have no resource to create a virtual machine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/ - see section "Tomcat". You could either upload your own tomcat as mentioned in this link OR you can just configure httpPlatform section in your web.config to override the JAVA_OPTS with any jvm parameter you want.

Thanks.

Comment: Changing web.config doesn't help. This: <environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS"    value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx1024m" /> causes a 500 error. I have changed the JVM according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425798/microsft-azure-installing-java-cryptography-extension-jce
Could that be part of the problem ?