# GeoServer WebArchive Redploy on Azure Tomcat AppService on cold start even not changed

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, geoserver

Following [this](https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/10/06/azure-app-service-deploying-a-java-webapp-geoserver-to-azure/) I have deployed GeoServer on Azure AppService using Tomcat 8.0.

Initially Tomcat automatically deploy it without any trouble except that it took over 5 minutes and any request to the website will just timeout after couple minutes showing a CGI related error message. However it will be up and running eventually.

However, I notice it from time to time randomly a request comes in would hit a cold start and Tomcat will re-deploy the web archive which would make the request having to wait for over 3 minutes. For example, examining the Catalina logs for 3rd Jan, it cold start re-deploy the web archive at 8am and then at 2pm it happens again. However there is no change to the web archive at all.

If user will get a 4 minutes wait randomly throughout the day on hitting the cold start, this would not be acceptable for our production use. So any help would be appreciated.

Not sure if this is related but I notice Tomcat has a bunch of setting like `autoDeploy` etc however I have zero experience with Tomcat and therefore if setting these setting will resolve my problem, I would like some help what would be the correct setting and more importantly how to set it on Azure AppService to disable the auto re-deploy?

Here is the Catalina logs:

```
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.950 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 10 2017 10:10:31 UTC
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.46.0
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows Server 2016
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             D:\Program Files\Java\zulu8.23.0.3-jdk8.0.144-win_x64\jre
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Azul Systems, Inc.
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46\conf\logging.properties
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.964 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46\conf\logging.properties
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsite.logdir=d:\home\LogFiles\
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsite.tempdir=D:\local\Temp
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dport.http=11790
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46\endorsed
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\local\Temp
03-Jan-2018 14:29:38.979 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\Program Files\Java\zulu8.23.0.3-jdk8.0.144-win_x64\bin;D:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Python27;;D:\home\GDAL\gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010-x64;.
03-Jan-2018 14:29:39.701 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-11790"]
03-Jan-2018 14:29:46.213 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
03-Jan-2018 14:29:46.225 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 10916 ms
03-Jan-2018 14:29:47.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
03-Jan-2018 14:29:47.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.46
03-Jan-2018 14:29:50.553 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\geoserver.war
03-Jan-2018 14:31:13.696 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:19.054 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities.loadGDAL GDAL Native Library loaded (version: 1.9.2)
03-Jan-2018 14:31:25.527 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:25.527 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:25.544 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:25.544 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:44.183 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:44.183 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:44.183 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:31:44.183 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.300 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\geoserver.war has finished in 221,747 ms
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.349 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.409 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT has finished in 60 ms
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.409 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\target
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.458 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\target has finished in 49 ms
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.615 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-11790"]
03-Jan-2018 14:33:32.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 226502 ms
```

Comment: what does the GeoServer log show? how much memory did you allocate to the JVM? if it is production critical why not deploy multiple JVMs and a load balancer?

Comment: @IanTurton it is azure app service. This has not gone live yet. We are testing it on a dev server where almost no load at all. The azure app service has been set to Always On. So I am not sure why at random time Tomcat would redeploy the GeoServer web archive when a http request comes in

Comment: Possibly an out of memory error, what does the log file show

Comment: @IanTurton searching for keyword `memory` or `exception` or `error` does not show any sign of out of memory. The Azure memory chart shows that it sit around 50% memory usage of the 1.75 GB RAM. I have scaled it up to 3.5GB plan to see if it helps.

In terms of logs, here are some wanings:
WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.checkContext Extension 
lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.

Comment: or WARNING [http-nio-127.0.0.1-17675-exec-7] java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.<init> Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 2.

Comment: please turn your logging level up to GeoTools Dev and then paste the log section relating to the crash into the question. Also if you have not allocated that memory to the JVM it will make no difference.

Comment: @IanTurton I have turned it to Verbose and hope can see something after a day. I have also found that I seems to be able to configure JVM by web.config as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518115/how-to-change-jvm-parameters-on-the-microsoft-azure-website. How could I make increase the memory allocation for the JVM?

Comment: I had assumed that you had read and understood http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html before attempting to deploy GeoServer for production.

Comment: @IanTurton After scale up to 2 cpu cores with 3.5g RAM, I don't seem to see the cold start problem anymore for these 2 days but we have not been testing extensively these 2 days due to other priority issues. I will consider this as fixed for now unless I notice another cold start. Thanks for your help.