# Setting JVM heap options in Azure App Service

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to deploy an app to the Azure App Service (free tier), and because of the memory limitations the app keeps getting killed as it uses too much memory.  Of course the easiest way to solve this is setting `-Xmx900m` on the JVM at startup, however none of the methods I've tried have worked so far.

What I have tried:

1. Added `-Xmx900m` to the web.config `httpPlatform` tag, in the `arguments` attribute (at the start).
2. Added `-Xmx900m` to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable (in the Application Settings)
3. Added `-Xmx900m` to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable using the `web.config` file.

The problem is I can't verify if any of these actually worked, because in Kudu I can't see the command line that was used or really do much to inspect the process beyond seeing how much memory it is using at any given moment.  It certainly seems as though the setting is being ignored in each of these cases, since the memory usage climbs to 1024MB then the process crashes with a memory allocation failure.

Is there anything I can do to set the max heap setting in Azure App Service Java applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you have java process in Kudu, you could check java process `PID` with `jps` then use `jmap -heap [pid]`  in jdk/bin directory and you will get the heap memory details.

If you don't have, you could create a `WebJob` to get the details.  I get the details and put it in the queue. Here is the sample code.

```
 public static  final String storageConnectionString =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                "AccountName=******;" +
                "AccountKey=*********;" +
                "EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

public static void main( String[] args )
{


    MemoryMXBean memorymbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    MemoryUsage usage = memorymbean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
    System.out.println("INIT HEAP: " + usage.getInit()/(1024*1024));
    System.out.println("MAX HEAP: " + usage.getMax()/(1024*1024));
    System.out.println("USE HEAP: " + usage.getUsed()/(1024*1024));
    System.out.println("\nFull Information:");
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Usage: "
            + memorymbean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
    System.out.println("Non-Heap Memory Usage: "
            + memorymbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage());


    CloudQueueMessage message=null;

    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue.
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference(**queuename**);

        // Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
        queue.createIfNotExists();

        // Create a message and add it to the queue.
        CloudQueueMessage errormessage = new CloudQueueMessage("INIT HEAP: " + usage.getInit()+
                                                                        "MAX HEAP: " + usage.getMax()+
                                                                        "USE HEAP: " + usage.getUsed() +
                                                                        "Heap Memory Usage: " + memorymbean.getHeapMemoryUsage()+
                                                                        "Non-Heap Memory Usage: " + memorymbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage());
        queue.addMessage(errormessage);

        // Download the approximate message count from the server.
        queue.downloadAttributes();

        // Retrieve the newly cached approximate message count.
        long cachedMessageCount = queue.getApproximateMessageCount();

        // Display the queue length.
        System.out.println(String.format("Queue length: %d", cachedMessageCount));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

IF you still have questions , please let me know.

Comment: I'm not trying to get information about the heap; I'm trying to *set* the max heap, a setting which it seems is being ignored by the JVM, as Kudu reports memory usage beyond the setting I used for -Xmx by the 'java' process.

Comment: You could use this to check whether your changes work. And the way you change JVM is correct , you  could refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26155140/10383250

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older thread, but just in case anyone stumbles upon this looking to fix this issue now, the answer depends on whether the app service is running under Dedicated/Premium or Consumption plans.

For app services running under dedicated or premium plans you use the JAVA_OPTS app settings.
For app services running under consumption plans you use “languageWorkers__java__arguments” app setting instead.

You can read more about that here as we are still waiting on the main doc to be updated for the difference regarding consumption plans.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/wiki/How-to-customize-JVM-options-on-Azure-Functions